# What is the use-case for a ConcurrentHashMap in Java? At the point which you have a second variable, it requires a lock, eliminating the benefit

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm

Imagine the below scenario:

```
String foo;
ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> bar;
```

Accessing `bar` can be done without taking a lock, but accessing `foo` cannot.

If we need to `foo` and `bar` together in order to perform meaningful work, what is the practical usecase for `ConcurrentHashMap`? At that point, since we're under a lock, we may as well use a regular hashmap right?

I'm having a hard time coming up with a case where you ONLY need a single `ConcurrentHashMap` variable in a highly-concurrent critical section of code.

Here's an example, sometimes this prints `199`, sometimes it prints `200`, but the `ConcurrentHashMap` is always correct:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

 class MyClass {
    private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private int myInt = 0;

    public void addToMap(int key, String value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    public void incrementInt() {
        myInt++;
    }

    public void runThreads() {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                addToMap(i, "Thread 1 - " + i);
                incrementInt();
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 100; i < 200; i++) {
                addToMap(i, "Thread 2 - " + i);
                incrementInt();
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("myInt = " + myInt);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.runThreads();
    }
}
```

Comment: `foo` is **immutable**. Please elaborate on why you need a lock...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, How is `foo` immutable?

Comment: Just as @ElliottFrisch pointed out, `String`s are immutable, and assigning a value to a variable is always an atomic action. Aside from this, having a thread-safe map is still beneficial since the datastructure is thread-safe. For example, if we all `computeIfAbsent(...)` in parallel from multiple threads witth the same key, at most one insert int he map will happen.

Comment: @SolomonSlow [because the docs says so](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: Let me edit the post, I should have written a better description, I apologize. I will give a more realistic scenario

Comment: @GavinRay, You are exactly right. When you need to preserve some invariant in which more than one variable or field is involved, then there's no way to do with without advisory locking (e.g., a `synchronized` block or a `ReentrantLock`. But, there _are_ applications in which just having a thread-safe `Map` _does_ solve some problem. There are even applications where just having an `AtomicInteger` can solve a problem.

Comment: @Turing85, You're saying that if OP added a statement to their example like, `foo`="Artichoke"`, then the compiler would forbid it or it would raise a run-time exception? I don't see anything in OP's code or description that would forbid it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I have not said such a thing. I said that assignment is an atomic operation. And immutability is not equivalent to `final` (i.e. "can only be assigned once").

Comment: @SolomonSlow The Javadoc link specifically says *Because String objects are immutable they can be shared.* Which appears to (not coincidentally) satisfy this specific use-case.

Comment: @Turing85, I don't see where `foo` is `final` in OP's example.

Comment: @SolomonSlow and I never said it is, quite the opposite: I explicitly said that assignment is atomic, i.e. accounting for the possibility of (re-)assigning a (new) value.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, OP's question is not about the `String` object to which `foo` might refer. OP is asking about the variable itself. OP is suggesting that the code is required to preserve some invariant relationship between _which_ `String` instance `foo` refers to and the contents of the map. OP is suggesting that the program cannot first change one and then change the other without temporarily breaking the invariant, and that therefore, some form of mutex locking is required.

Comment: @Turing85, I'm sorry. I must have misunderstood which comment you were responding to. I thought that your comment implied that `foo` was immutable. But again. The fact that assignments to a single variable are immutable is no help when the design requires the both the variable assignment _and_ a change to the `Map` to be done in a single, atomic operation.

Comment: I added an example

Comment: @GavinRay you are using non-thread-safe code, the postincrement in `incrementInt()` (this is a read and a write, both in isolation are atomic, but the chain of read and then write is not). If we use an `AtomicInteger` instead or protect the method with `synchronized`, the program will work as expected

Comment: @GavinRay, That example would sometimes print the wrong number even if you completely removed the `Map`. Your `incrementInt()` method is not thread safe independent of how `myInt` relates to any other data in the program.

Comment: Imagine a real estate app where some `House`s in a `ConcurrentHashMap` are for sale, and some not. If the app also requires an `AtomicInteger count` that holds the number of houses for sale then, it's impossible for a thread to change the state of a `House` without temporarily making the `count` wrong. If you need to _guarantee_ that no other thread can _ever_ see a wrong `count`, then you need a mutex. The fact that `count` is atomic doesn't help. If `house.isForSale` is an `AtomicBoolean`, that doesn't help either. Only a mutex will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Solomon, I'll accept that an answer if you post it!